# Running PHP scripts directly with php.exe

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to run a PHP script through PHP.exe.
The script connects to a MSSQL server and inserts some data, that I should be able to see from a php page through the browser. The issue is, sometimes the script runs fine and data is created, sometimes nothing happens.

This is the script file:

```
<?php
    include('default_code.php');
    $insquery = "INSERT INTO Messaggi (Object, Text, user_ID, isRead, Time) "
            . "VALUES ('Title', 'Text', 5, 'FALSE', CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 120))";
    $ins = sqlsrv_query($conn, $insquery)
            or die(print_r(array(sqlsrv_errors())));
?>
```

This is the default_code.php file, containing the connection string for the database:

```
<?php
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( '(localdb)\v11.0', array('AttachDBFileName'=>'C:\SIAtest\Database\SIAtest.mdf','Database'=>'SIAtest'))
        or die ("Connection problem: " . print_r(array(sqlsrv_errors())));
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
?>
```

It should be a fairly simple task, I just can't understand why the script does not always properly run.

Comment: close the connection after query execution `sqlsrv_close($conn);`

Comment: "does not always properly run" - errors? Warnings? How does the improper run look? What is the difference between that and a "proper" run?

Comment: @Piskvor There are no errors or warnings, just the data isn't inserted in the database.

Comment: @SKRocks closing the connection isn't solving the problem, but thanks for trying. It is still better to close the connection everytime. I forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your code for next
script file

```
    <?php
    include('default_code.php');
    $insquery = "INSERT INTO Messaggi (Object, Text, user_ID, isRead, Time) "
            . "VALUES ('Title', 'Text', 5, 'FALSE', CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 120))";
    $ins = sqlsrv_query($conn, $insquery);
    if ($ins === false){
            die(print_r(array(sqlsrv_errors())));
    }
?>
```

default_code.php

```
    <?php
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( '(localdb)\v11.0', array('AttachDBFileName'=>'C:\SIAtest\Database\SIAtest.mdf','Database'=>'SIAtest'));
    if ($conn === false){
        die ("Connection problem: " . print_r(array(sqlsrv_errors())));
    }
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
?>
```